# How to change the name of a measure in dax, according to the current month?

Tags: powerbi, dax, measure

```
MedidaMes-1 = CALCULATE(SelecaoMedidas[MedidaSelecionada],
           DATEDIFF(date(2023,12,01),dCalendario[Data],MONTH)=-1)
```

In this case, instead of "MedidaMes-1" I would like "Nov/23"

I don´t know where to start.

Comment: You can't rename measures dynamically. However depending on your visual you may have other options. Update your question with which visual you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this with Field Parameter function in PBI. Modeling - New Parameter - Fields. After this you have to add measures.
Before you may create measure for date, something like this:

```
Month-3 = EOMonth(EDATE(max(calendar[date]),-3),0)
```

After that you can use it to customize name of your measure with Field Paramater:

```
constructor2 = {
("measure , "&Format([Month-3], "mmm yyyy"), NAMEOF([measure Month-3]), 1),
("measure , "&Format([Month-2], "mmm yyyy"), NAMEOF([measure Month-2]), 2),
("measure , "&Format([Month-1], "mmm yyyy"), NAMEOF([measure Month-1]), 3),
("measure , "&Format([Month-0], "mmm yyyy"), NAMEOF([measure Month-0]), 4)}
```

Add parameter on visual and enjoy result. That is solution i used to.